# How to map with different parameters - ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm creating some tests and I would like to create an array of objects passing different parameters to the constructor, is there a smart way of doing that?

For example, suppose I have this code:

```
 foos = 3.times.map{ Foo.new("a") }
```

This code would give me an array with 3 `foo`'s, but all of them initialized with the `"a"` parameter.

I would rather have an array where the first one is initialized with `"a"`, the second with `"b"` and the third with `"c"`, like it would if did this:

```
foos = [Foo.new("a"),Foo.new("b"),Foo.new("c")]
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
%w(a b c).map { |s| Foo.new(s) }
```

In case you don't know

```
%w(a b c)
```

is a shorter way to say

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Might be more accurate to say "a shorter way to say `['a', 'b', 'c']`" since `%w` doesn't allow for string interpolation like `%W` does. Yes, nit picking.

Answer (score 3):

Going a bit deeper on your question, I'm going to suggest you two libraries: [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) and [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker). None is Rails nor Rspec specific.

With Factory Girl you can define factories to create test data and with Faker you can associate randomized data to your factories.

I'm suggesting these two libraries because creating test data for simple use cases is easy, but it starts to get very complicated when you have more complex relationships between objects.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
class Foo < Struct.new(:bar)
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    bar Faker::Number.digit
  end
end

FactoryGirl.build_list(:foo, 3)
=> [#<struct Foo bar=3>, #<struct Foo bar=2>, #<struct Foo bar=7>]

FactoryGirl.build(:foo)
=> #<struct Foo bar=5>

    FactoryGirl.build(:foo, bar: 2)
=> #<struct Foo bar=2>
```

Here are [more examples](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) on how powerful Factory Girl is. Just remember that you need to use the `build*` methods instead of `create*` methods, because `create*` methods also call on `save` to persist the data when using it with a persistence layer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to offer an alternative:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
Array.new(arr.size) { |i| Foo.new arr[i] }
#=>
#[#<Foo:0x000000025db798 @arg="a">,
# #<Foo:0x000000025db748 @arg="b">,
# #<Foo:0x000000025db6d0 @arg="c">]
```